# Laravel 8: How do i verify the users email address after registration without having to require login information?

Tags: php, laravel, email-verification, laravel-8, laravel-jetstream

I set up a Laravel 8 installation with Jetstream and implemented a custom user registration, where an event is fired after a successful creation of the database record `event(new Registered($user));`.

The initial registration process should not require a password yet, because only a selected set of users should be able to login to a dashboard in the future.

After the registration the user gets an email with a verification link, however he still needs to login in order to get verified.

I tried to remove the auth middleware in `routes/web.php`, however i get an error message after attempting to verify a users email address.

```
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
  $request->fulfill();
  return view('home');
})->middleware(['auth','signed'])->name('verification.verify');
```

Is it possible to verify a users email address without login information?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible.

You can modify files directly in Jetstream packages however I will present method adding new files and keeping original packages untouched.

Add new Controller App\Http\Controllers\VerifyEmailController.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\VerifyEmailResponse;

class VerifyEmailController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::findOrFail($request->route('id'));

        if (! hash_equals(sha1($user->getEmailForVerification()), (string) $request->route('hash'))) {
            throw new AuthorizationException;
        }

        if ($user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
            return app(VerifyEmailResponse::class);
        }

        if ($user->markEmailAsVerified()) {
            event(new Verified($user));
        }

        return app(VerifyEmailResponse::class);
    }
}
```

In web.php add a new route without `auth` middleware:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\VerifyEmailController;
    
Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
    ->middleware(['signed', 'throttle:6,1'])
    ->name('verification.verify');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I can confirm that it's working

Comment: @jsowa I can't help but notice you're not verifying the hash. The original code checks for it.

Comment: @Kessir, that's true. It's not quite safe now.

Answer (score 0):

Open **config/fortify.php** file and **uncomment** the `Features::emailVerification(),`  line.

```
'features' => [
    Features::registration(),
    Features::resetPasswords(),
    // Features::emailVerification(),
    Features::updateProfileInformation(),
    Features::updatePasswords(),
    Features::twoFactorAuthentication([
        'confirmPassword' => true,
    ]),
],
```

Next go to the **User modal** and implement the **MustVerifyEmail interface**.

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail{
   use Notifiable;
```

}

Note: you should have knowledge about [Mail in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail)

Comment: This solution may only work if Fortify is installed. The Author didn't say anything like that.

Comment: noted, mybad. thanks for the feedback, i will fix it latter.