# Laravel 8 email verification issue - Call to a member function getKey() on null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

For whatever reason, I'm having issues with email verification in Laravel 8.  The email verification link is sending find, but when a user clicks the link, this error is returned:  "Call to a member function getKey() on null" caused by The EmailVericationRequest.php file on php.  Here is the code for that file:

```
     <?php
    
    namespace Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
    
    use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Verified;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
    
    class EmailVerificationRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        /**
         * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
         *
         * @return bool
         */
        public function authorize()
        {
            if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('id'),
   /*this line is casing the issue*/ (string) $this->user()->getKey())) {
                return false;
            }
    
            if (! hash_equals((string) $this->route('hash'),
                              sha1($this->user()->getEmailForVerification()))) {
                return false;
            }
    
            return true;
        }
    
        /**
         * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
         *
         * @return array
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                //
            ];
        }
    
        /**
         * Fulfill the email verification request.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function fulfill()
        {
            if (! $this->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
                $this->user()->markEmailAsVerified();
    
                event(new Verified($this->user()));
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * Configure the validator instance.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
         * @return void
         */
        public function withValidator($validator)
        {
            return $validator;
        }
    }
```

Here is the route from auth.php:

```
Route::get('/verify-email/{id}/{hash}', [VerifyEmailController::class, '__invoke'])
                ->middleware('guest')
                ->name('verification.verify');
```

Does anybody know what would be causing this?

Comment: `$this->user()` is `null`, so trying to access `null->getKey()` is throwing that error. Is the user logged in when they click that link? Considering you have it linked to the `guest` middleware (`guest` means no one is logged in), you may need to take a step back and reevaluate your approach 

Comment: If there is guest middleware then the user isn’t authenticated. So how can the user have a key?

Comment: So there is no way to use the built in functionality if user is not logged in? I mean, I want the user to verify the email before being able to login. Is that possible?

Comment: That is possible but would require some tweaking @Luciano. You could refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64172138/laravel-8-how-do-i-verify-the-users-email-address-after-registration-without-ha

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, if you change middleware to auth, the problem will be solved

Because you are not logged in, and you want to access something that requires the user to be logged in